# How to use "internal" for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

This probably has been answered somewhere, but sadly I don't really know which keywords to look for, so let me describe what I mean with "internal" for loop via this code snippet that I'm using:

```py
@htf.measures(*(htf.Measurement("{}".format(i)) for i in ["v1", "v2"]))
```

Here, the for loop is used in a way that doesn't work the way I've known it to do (til now), example:

```py
for i in x:
    #Do something
```

It seems like a very handy way to use a for loop, so I'd like to understand how it works. I could imagine the * operator to have something to do with it, but as far as I can see its only a multiplicator, right?

This is what I am trying to do with the "new" for function:

```py
tmp = [].append(*("P{}".format(id) for id in range(1, 5, 1)))
```

This returns an Error, saying append doesn't take 4 arguments, so I guess the for loop works somehow, but what I meant to do was to make it append 4 items.

Finally: I have two questions, 1. What is this for loop called and how can I google it, 2. how do I make the "append 4 times" thingy work?

Comment: I think you are looking for the term: `List Comprehension`. Did you mean: `tmp = ["P{}".format(id) for id in range(1, 5, 1)]`?

Comment: Was about to post same as an answer :) If you're appending to an empty list all the time, might as well use a list comprehension to start with!

Comment: The keywords you are looking for are _generator expression_, _unpacking_ and _list comprehension_.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at them :)